# change ESXI host IP in VCSA

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I have 3 esxi 6.7 hosts registered in VCSA.
I want to change my esxi host ips. When I do in ESXI DCUI, eg from .120 to .20, VCSA keeps the old IPs .120 and cannot connect to the hosts anymore. 
When I click remove and re-add, VCSa says it will lose all configs.

How can I update the ESXI IPs in VCSA?

Answer (score 0):

1) You should right click on the host and remove from Inventory

[image]

2) Change the Management IP address from ESXi or DCUI wherever you prefer.

3) Try to login in the new ESXi address on your web browser to verify the IP change.

4) Then you should add the host again on the Vcenter. With adding/removing from inventory you will not loose any host configuration.